# run command after deploy using Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, heroku-cli

I'm setting up `Gitlab CI/CD` to automate deployment to heroku app with every push.

currently my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like

```
production:
  type: deploy
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=koober-production --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
  only:
  - master
```

This works fine and deployment is successful and application is working.

But, I need to run few commands after successful deployment to migrate database.

At present, I need to do this manually by running command from terminal

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate -a myapp
```

**How can I automate this to run this command after deployment?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using `--run` flag to run command using `dpl`

```
stages:
  - deploy

production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=koober-production --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY --run='python manage.py migrate && python manage.py create_initial_users'
  only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 1):

First `types` are [deprecated](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#types), you should use `stages`.
Back to the original question, I think you can use a new stage/type for this purpose.
Declaring something like:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  - post_deploy

post_production:
  stage: post_deploy
  script:
  - heroku run python manage.py migrate -a myapp
  only:
  - master
```

This should then execute only in the case the deplyment succeds.

Comment: here `production` is fine as this stage deploy the application to heroku. You mean I need to add one more `post_production` block with `stage: post_production` which will run migrate command?

Comment: I tried it but it gives `/bin/bash: line 63: heroku: command not found`.

Comment: So the script and heroku command are not part of the gitlab worker. Then i need to know what the py script does and especially where this script is located (is it part of the source code?)